# find area of darkened figure

Tags: geometry

[image]

We know that length of diameter $AB=6$; $CA=2\sqrt{3}$; 
 We should find area of darkened figure `I have tried  following :`

```
Since $AB$ is diameter  we  can say $ACB$ is right triangle  so
```

we can caluclate  area of $ABC$, but my question is how calculate   area  of this triangle inside circle? Please help me.

Comment: Perhaps you could be able to find $\angle ABC$ using some trinometric functions and then use it to find the angle $\angle AOD$, where D is the intersection of $BC$ with the circle. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the metric data you can compute the angle at $B$ since $\tan B = \sqrt 3/3$.
Let $D$ be the intersection of $BC$ with the circle. Since the angle at $B$ is known  and $OB=OD$, you can easily compute the area of the circular sector $AOD$ and of the triangle $BOD$.

Comment: one question  area of BOD is clear but for AOD i need angle  and how  find it when i  connect D and center of circle?

Comment: @user3196: The angle at $B$ is known, as lhf wrote. Its tangent is $1/\sqrt{3}$, so it is $30^\circ$. A little angle chasing shows that therefore $\angle AOD$ is $60^\circ$, so the circular sector has area one-sixth of the area of the circle. You now only need to find the area of $\triangle BOD$.

Comment: The area of $\triangle BOD$ is the same as that of $\triangle AOD$, an equilateral triangle of edge 3.

Answer (score 2):

$\triangle ABC$ is half an equilateral triangle making $\angle BCA = \pi /3$ and $\angle CBA = \pi /6$, so if $D$ is the intersection of $BC$ and the circle then $\triangle OAD$ is equilateral, and with the circle radius of 3 you can calculate all the areas.

Comment: thanks   a lot   i have also read  wiki page about inscribed angles everything is clear now for me thanks guys